# Problemas con Merge en rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

Buen día soy nuevo en esto de la programación en Rstudio, estoy trabajando con 2 bases de datos:
La primera tiene 45009 registros
La Segunda tienen 24
Estoy intentado cruzarlas (como en excel) y estoy utilizando la funcion merge, este es el código:

```
> BasePeS <- merge(BasePeS, BaseCObrador, by = "Codi", all.x=TRUE)
```

Ambas bases comparten una fila que tiene el titulo "Codi" al ejecutarlo me arroja el siguiente error:

> Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin ||
> !anyDuplicated(f__,  :    Join results in 45247 rows; more than 45033
> = nrow(x)+nrow(i). Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try
> by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation. If
> you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE.
> Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki,
> Stack Overflow and data.table issue tracker for advice.

Si utilizo allow.cartesian=TRUE me elimina la mitad de los registros cosa que no quiero, perdón si no me explique bien soy nuevo...

Cambios

@mpaladino Primero realice la validación:

```
is.data.table(BasePeS) TRUE is.data.table(BaseCObrador) FALSE
```

Loc converti a data frame

as.data.frame(BasePeS)
as.data.frame(BaseCObrador)

Revise que ya coincidieran ambas tablas:

```
    is.data.frame(BasePeS) 1 TRUE is.data.frame(BaseCObrador) 1 TRUE
```

Volví a correr el merge, pero aparece el mismos error:

Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__, : Join results in 45247 rows; more than 45033 = nrow(x)+nrow(i). Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation. If you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE. Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and data.table issue tracker for advice.

Les comparto ejemplos de la base de datos:

BasePes

introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí

M-pago O.Cobrador Codi EFE 901017003 7003 EFE 901017003 7003 EFE 901017003 7003 EFE 901000067 67 EFE 901017003 7003 EFE 901017003 7003 ICC 80600001 8060 EFE 901017003 7003 ICC 80600001 8060 ICC 80600001 8060

"BaseCObrador" donde están todas las variables que pueden aparecer en "Codi" en "BasePes"

introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí

Codi Nombre.O.Cobrador 7006 Banamex 7007 Banorte 7009 Scotiabank 7012 Santander 7017 BanRegio 7029 Bancomer 7039 Inbursa 7070 HSBC 8029 BBVA DOMICILIADOS 8030 DOMICILIADOS INBURSA 8031 BANAMEX DOMICILIADO 8032 AMERICAN EXPRESS 7003 OXXO 7004 7 Eleven 7005 Soriana 7038 Datalogic Farmacia del Ahorro 7104 Arcus 8050 Evo Payments APP 7015 HEB 7032 Paga Todo 7038 Datalogic 7083 Red-efectiva 8050 Evo Payments Oficina Virtual 8060 IACEPTA

Comment: Hola Diego, bienvenido. Por el mensaje de error parece que las "bases de datos" son objetos `data.table`. Quizás ahí venga el problema. Podrías probar coercinándolos a `data.frame` con `as.data.frame(BasePes)` y probar para ver si el problema persiste. Adicionalmente: si los datos no hay problemas de privacidad/confidencialidad podrías poner un ejemplo de los mismos, ayudaría mucho a encontrar una solución.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya realice el cambio a data frame quedo de la siguiente manera

Comment: @mpaladino abajo puse lo que realice espero me puedas ayudar

Comment: 1. ¿asignaste cuando pasaste a data.frame? Digamos `BasePes <- as.data.frame(BasePes)`. 2. Los data.table también son data.frame, si validas con `is.data.frame(un_data.table)` te regresará `TRUE`. 3. Hice la prueba con los datos que pusiste  de ejemplo, asegurándome de que sean data.frame y no data.table  y creo el merge se hace bien, al menos no me da el error que estás recibiendo.

Comment: @mpaladino gracias por el tip de las respuestas, agregue la información arriba, corri el BasePes <- as.data.frame(BasePes), pero ahora me surge una duda, la base inicial tiene 45009 registros pero al hacer el merge me duplica ciertos valores y el suben los registros a 45247, esto por que sucede?

Comment: @mpaladino ya vi por que me duplico los registros, en la base Cobrador tenia codigos repetidos con diferente nombre, MUCHAS GRACIAS, ya pude realizar el cruce, que tengas excelente día...

Comment: ¿Puedes verificar que ya no se presenta el problema cuando ambos son data.frame? Si es así podrías responder tu propia pregunta y explicar como lo resolviste. Sería buena idea por si alguien en el futuro tiene el mismo problema, así  encontraría facilmente una solución.